# How to pass data over an API web function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, throttling, actionfilterattribute

I want to build a web API with throttle:

```
[ThrottleFilter(RequestLimit: 2, TimeoutInSeconds: 6,ThrottleGroup:"//This one")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/allow-more")]
public HttpResponseMessage HelloWorld2(string a)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World2");
}
```

The problem is how can I fill ThrottleGroup with my dynamic data,that uses ActionFilterAttribute?
I have tried to call this as a parameter.I know that it is impossible,
can anyone help me?

Comment: You could probably create your own filter, inheriting from ThrottleFilter, which populates the ThrottleGroup dynamically

Comment: Not sure if its applicable to your scenario, I would have tried overriding the Action and fill in the ThrottleGroup `public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)`.

Comment: @MukulVarshney already use that thing :(